# Извлечение данных из удаленного сервера с помощью SSH доступа

Tags: ssh, filezilla

Есть ли смысл выгружать файлы из хостинга через SSH или все же прибегнуть к старому доброму FileZilla-клиенту, какой из них быстрее b безопаснее??

Comment: Не ясен вопрос: вы делаете бекап? Работаете на сервере с файлами? Сравниваете ssh с ... ftp или sftp, или с ftp поверх VPN? Если работаете на Linux, просто замонтируйте через sshfs удаленную машинку к себе в файловую систему, будет работать - не отличишь.

Comment: допустим я делаю бэкап или  скачиваю нужные данные, тогда просто работать с FTP клиентом, а зачем тогда мы получаем доступ через SSH?? или  я достаточна осведомлен...

Comment: Если файлов много, замучаетесь выкачивать. Лучше паковать через tar и скачивать любым способом.

Comment: есть замечательный tmux, который всё это в фоне будет делать

Comment: буду учитывать, благодарю за  столь ценную инфу ребята!

Comment: **Filezilla** тоже работает по `ssh`